# WPF-Cómo puedo actualizar los datos de una ventana al cerrar otra?

Tags: c#, wpf

Tengo 2 ventanas en mi aplicación WPF. En mi ventana Main tengo un Listbox que muestra los archivos que hay en un fichero. Este es el método que tengo escrito en mi MainWindow.

```
 private void Entorno_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Window1 window1 = new Window1();
       window1.Owner = this;
       window1.ShowDialog();
        

    }
```

En mi window1, se pueden generar archivos cuya ubicación debería de verse en el ListBox pero no se visualiza.
Me gustaría que al cerrar mi ventana window1. la ventana MainWindow se actualizase o se relanzase.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el evento *Closed*

```
    private void Entorno_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window w = new Window();//crea nueva ventana
        w.Closed += new EventHandler(AccioneRealizar);//asigna la funcion a realizar en el cierre de la ventana
        w.Show();  //muestra la vetana  
    }
    private void AccioneRealizar(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Se cerro la ventana");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que usas `ShowDialog()` en vez de `Show()`. En este caso estás desaprovechando esta función, pues, al igual que con la solución de Emmanuel, puedes enlazar a un código secundario que "relance" tu MainWindow, entendiendo que "relanzar" no es volver a abrirlo sino recargar sus datos.

Yo lo haría así:

```
private void Entorno_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dialog = new window1();
    if (dialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        RelanzarMainWindow();
    }       
}

private void RelanzarMainWindow()
{
    //
}
```

Cuando usas `ShowDialog()` puedes anidar código dentro para hacer cosas que ocurrirán **CUANDO LA VENTANA SE CIERRE** pudiendo incluso acceder a datos que hayas gestionado en esa ventana.

Incluso puedes verificar si `ShowDialoig()` es `True` para verificar si se cerró con Aceptar o no.

Suerte.